# Madgwick's sensor fusion algorithm on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-motion, coordinate-transformation, sensor-fusion

i'm trying to run [Madgwick's sensor fusion algorithm](http://www.x-io.co.uk/open-source-imu-and-ahrs-algorithms/) on iOS. Since the code is open source i already included it in my project and call the methods with the provided sensor values.

But it seems, that the algorithm expects the sensor measurements in a different coordinate system. The Apple CoreMotion Sensor System is given on the right side, Madgewick's on the left. Here is the picture of the [different coordinate systems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E26ZK.jpg). Both systems follow the right hand rule.
For me it seems like there is a 90 degree rotation around the z axis. But this didn't work.

[image: different coordinate systems]

I also tried to flip x and y (and invert z) axis as suggested by [other stackoverflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13499838/delay-in-yaw-pitch-and-roll-values/16214450#16214450) for WP but this didn't work also. So do you have a hint?
Would be perfect if Madgwick's alogithm output could be in the same system as the CoreMotion output (CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXMagneticNorthZVertical).

Furthermore I'm looking for a good working value for **betaDef** on the iPhone. **betaDef** is kind of the proportional gain and is currently set to 0.1f.

Any help on how to achieve the goal would be appreciated.

Comment: were you able to achieve the task?

Comment: No, sorry. Don't have a Mac anymore.

Comment: thanks for a quick reply

Comment: What works already please? Madgwick's filter works as follows: 1) Use the current attitude to calculate accelerometer/magnetometer attitude errors in angle-axis form 2) Subtract a bit of these errors to the gyroscope axis-angle form 3) Update the attitude quaternion integrating the corrected axis-angle values. Do you have any of these steps working separately? Madgwick's filter shall work in any reference frame but the resulting quaternion will be in the reference frame of the input data. I believe you might have another problem altogether. What do you get if you apply the filter as is?

Comment: Hi flix. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Hi flix, did you solve the problem? Could you please to share your solution

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to write this in objective c, but here's how I accomplished the coordinate transformations in vanilla c. I also wanted to rotate the orientation so that +y is north. This translation is also reflected in the below method.

This method expects a 4 element quaternion in the form of wxyz, and returns a translated quaternion in the same format:

```
void madgeq_to_openglq(float *fMadgQ, float *fRetQ) {
  float fTmpQ[4];
  // Rotate around Z-axis, 90 degres:
  float fXYRotationQ[4] = { sqrt(0.5), 0, 0, -1.0*sqrt(0.5) };

  // Inverse the rotation vectors to accomodate handedness-issues:
  fTmpQ[0] = fMadgQ[0];
  fTmpQ[1] = fMadgQ[1] * -1.0f;
  fTmpQ[2] = fMadgQ[2];
  fTmpQ[3] = fMadgQ[3] * -1.0f;

  // And then store the translated Rotation into ret:
  quatMult((float *) &fTmpQ, (float *) &fXYRotationQ, fRetQ);
}

// Quaternion Multiplication operator. Expects its 4-element arrays in wxyz order 
void quatMult(float *a, float *b, float *ret) {
  ret[0] = (b[0] * a[0]) - (b[1] * a[1]) - (b[2] * a[2]) - (b[3] * a[3]);
  ret[1] = (b[0] * a[1]) + (b[1] * a[0]) + (b[2] * a[3]) - (b[3] * a[2]);
  ret[2] = (b[0] * a[2]) + (b[2] * a[0]) + (b[3] * a[1]) - (b[1] * a[3]);
  ret[3] = (b[0] * a[3]) + (b[3] * a[0]) + (b[1] * a[2]) - (b[2] * a[1]);

  return;
}
```

Hope that helps!